# Swap key and value of a nested map recursively in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, hashmap, swap

How can I write a recursive method in Java that takes in a nested map and swaps the key and its value. But since it's a nested map, a key or a value can also be a map and it should also be swapped, if that's the case. So far I only got this:

```
public class MyRekursion {
    public static <K, V> HashMap<V, K> deepReverseMap(Map<K, V> nestedMap) {
        HashMap<V, K> rev = new HashMap<V, K>();

        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : nestedMap.entrySet()){
            K key = entry.getKey();
            V val = entry.getValue();
            if (key instanceof Map){
                // ???
                // key = (K)deepReverseMap((Map<K, V>)key);
            }
            if (val instanceof Map){
                // ???
                // val = (V)deepReverseMap((Map<K, V>)val);
            }
            rev.put(val, key);
        }

    return rev;
    }
}
```

Casting the return value of deepReverseMap() to K or V is probably wrong. How can I write this method correctly?

Comment: Let's say you have a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` - your code expects to create a `Map<Map<String, Integer>, String>`, so there is no way you can swap the keys and values of the map. Now if the input is a `Map<String, Object>` which happens to contain some maps as values, it's different.

Comment: Can you provide sample input / expected output (a complex example please)?

Comment: This smells a little like a homework question...

Comment: I run some tests with your code, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed code seems to work if you take out the comments. I would suggest to write some code along these lines for conciseness:

```
public static <K, V> HashMap<V, K> deepReverseMap(Map<K, V> nestedMap) {
    HashMap<V, K> rev = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : nestedMap.entrySet()) {
        K key = entry.getKey();
        V val = entry.getValue();
        rev.put(val instanceof Map ? (V) deepReverseMap((Map<K, V>) val) : val,
                key instanceof Map ? (K) deepReverseMap((Map<K, V>) key) : key);
    }
    return rev;
}
```

or with streams:

```
public static <K, V> HashMap<V, K> deepReverseMap(Map<K, V> nestedMap) {
    return nestedMap.entrySet().stream().collect(HashMap::new, (m, e) -> {
        final K key = e.getKey();
        final V val = e.getValue();
        m.put(Map.class.isInstance(val) ? (V) deepReverseMap((Map<K, V>) val) : val,
                Map.class.isInstance(key) ? (K) deepReverseMap((Map<K, V>) key) : key);
    }, (k, v) -> {});
}
```

You cannot avoid the unchecked cast though.

Here is a simple test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> m = new HashMap<>();

    Map<String, Integer> m1 = new HashMap<>();
    m1.put("s1", 1);
    m.put(1, m1);

    Map<String, Integer> m2 = new HashMap<>();
    m2.put("s2", 2);
    m.put(2, m2);

    Map<String, Integer> m3 = new HashMap<>();
    m3.put("s3", 3);
    m3.put("s3_1", 31);
    m.put(3, m3);
    System.out.println(m);

    Map<Map<String, Integer>, Integer> res = deepReverseMap(m);
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

This test will reverse the keys and values in the nested map too:

```
{1={s1=1}, 2={s2=2}, 3={s3=3, s3_1=31}}
{{3=s3, 31=s3_1}=3, {2=s2}=2, {1=s1}=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no typesafe way to do it in Java, You need to use unchecked casts:

```
if (key instanceof Map){
    key = (K) deepReverseMap((Map<?, ?>)key);
}
if (val instanceof Map){
    val = (V) deepReverseMap((Map<?, ?>)val);
}
```